# Find an imported python functions syntax

Tags: python

I am trying to understand a python class and its use. Here is an example of its use on Linux:

```
from Lima import Andor
from lima import Core

cam = Andor.Camera("/usr/local/etc/andor", 0)
```

Here is the source of the package: https://github.com/esrf-bliss/Lima-camera-andor. I have installed this package on windows, however there is no documentation for its use or syntax. I would like to know what I should use instead of `"/usr/local/etc/andor"` for my system. Is there any way to look at the source code for this `Andor` class?

EDIT:

actually running the example code above returns:

`runfile('C:/Users/BioPhotonics/.spyder-py3/untitled0.py',` wdir='C:/Users/BioPhotonics/.spyder-py3')
`Traceback (most recent call last):

`File "C:\Users\BioPhotonics\.spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 14, in`
`   cam = Andor.Camera("/usr/local/etc/andor", 0)

`Exception: Hardware: lima::Andor::Camera::Camera(C:\miniconda3\conda-`bld\lima-camera-andor_1568271992368\work\src\AndorCamera.cpp, 120): `InvalidValue: Invalid Camera number

Comment: Have you tried `help(Andor)`?

Comment: ```InvalidValue: Invalid Camera number``` - Did you check this ?

Comment: I have tried help(andor) to no avail. The invalid camera number error is probably due to the path I'm passing, as this is definitely wrong. I thought I would be able to "see" what Andor.Camera() requires as arguments? but maybe that's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for the Andor.Camera class is in the [`src/AndorCamera.cpp`](https://github.com/esrf-bliss/Lima-camera-andor/blob/master/src/AndorCamera.cpp) file. The parameter you're having problem with is a config directory, which is passed to the `Initialize` function of the Andor C SDK.

On Oxford instruments, there appear to be two versions of this SDK, but only version 2 has this function, so I suppose that's the one the library's using. You can download the documentation for the SDK [here](https://andor.oxinst.com/downloads/view/andor-sdk2-software-manual). Page 211 documents the `Initialize` function, which expects a config directory containing at least `Detector.ini`. I don't know where (or even if) that directory is created when installing the Andor driver pack on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

`Andor.__file__` will tell you the file used to define the module `Andor`. (Or, if `Andor` is not itself a module, you can import `Lima` and check `Lima.__file__`.)

Comment: Thank ou, however all that is there is an init file for the Andoe class which states from Lima import Core
from limaandor import Andor as _A
globals().update(_A.__dict__)